# How to find the values of $\alpha$ for which the integral converges?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\arctan^\alpha (x^2-x^3)}{(\ln x)^2\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})^{2\alpha-1}}\,dx$$
i was trying to use taylor series expansion  to solve it , but having difficulty after some steps because it becomes to messy , any help will be appreciated thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that as $x\to 1$, $\log(x)\sim x-1$, $\arctan(x^2-x^3)\sim 1-x$, and $\cos(\pi x/2)\sim 1-x$.

And as $x\to 0$, $\arctan(x^2-x^3)\sim x^2$.

Comment: thanks @Dr.MV , then when $x\to 0$, $\ln(x)\to \infty$ so will the integral diverge ?

Comment: Except the infinity appears in the denominator

Comment: The term $\frac1{\log^2(x)}$ is not a problem near $x=0$ even thought $\log(x)\to -\infty $.